# XPath with predicate: How to avoid quadratic time increase

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider this simplified Adobe Premiere project file:

```
<Project>
    <Sequences>
        <UID.1>a</UID.1>
        <UID.2>b</UID.2>
        <UID.3>c</UID.3>
    </Sequences>
</Project>
<Sequence ObjectUID="a"> ... </Sequence>
<Sequence ObjectUID="b"> ... </Sequence>
<Sequence ObjectUID="c"> ... </Sequence>
<Sequence ObjectUID="x"> ... </Sequence>
```

The goal is to find all Sequence elements that are referenced by *Project/Sequences/UID.N*

I constructed this Xpath query:

```
/Sequence[@ObjectUID=
  /Project/Nodes/*[starts-with(local-name(),"UID.")]
]
```

The problem with this is, that with a very large XML file (100 MB), even with only 20 Sequence elements in it, and 10000s of other siblings at the same level, the search takes many seconds.

If I instead only gather the inner query's results, i.e. from

```
/Project/Nodes/*[starts-with(local-name(),"UID.")]
```

and then iterate over the 20 UIDs, fetching each Sequence by their ObjectUID via `/PremiereData/Sequence[@ObjectUID='a']` and so on, it is very fast.

This suggests to me that the Xpath processor does not, as I'd expect, first evaluate the (and invariable) inner expression once, and then selects the outer expr's elements, but instead first fetches all Sequences and then re-evaluates the inner predicate for each of them, and that's what's making it so slow.

Am I right on this? And can I change the query so that this won't happen, or maybe add hints to tell the expression evaluator that the predicate is invariable?

Comment: Technically the performance is quadratic, not exponential. Quadratic goes 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64... while exponential goes 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128. Might seem a pedantic distinction, but it's actually a useful diagnostic to know which pattern the numbers follow.

Comment: I've thought about that, even wrote "quadratic or exponential" originally, since I could not figure it out. I've updated the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the processor is re-evaluating the expressions in your predicates and you would see a performance boost if you first select the UID element values and bind to a variable, and then use that variable in the predicate filter of `Sequence` elements.

```
let $uid := /PremiereData/Project/Sequences/*[starts-with(local-name(),'UID')] 
return /PremiereData/Sequence[@ObjectUID = $uid]
```

Comment: Note that "let $x :=" only becomes available in XPath from version 3.0 onwards.

Comment: That's probably the best answer for providing a solution, even though my XML toolkit is apparently not supporting v3, yet.

Answer (score 2):

Most XPath processors do not do any intelligent join optimization, they just use nested loops. Saxon-EE is the only processor I'm aware of that optimizes joins in the way you suggest.

If you're in XSLT then using xsl:key is the usual workaround, but in pure XPath there's no easy answer - especially if it's XPath 1.0.